# ModeShape setup and access from external application

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, webdav, document-management, modeshape

We have a clustered JEE application on JBoss EAP 4.0.x
I am trying to setup JBoss Modeshape repository to store a few documents (mostly PDF). I need to be able to upload and download the documents from my JEE application to the Modeshape repository. I need to setup a failover Modeshape repository in another unix box that could be backed up from the primary nightly.

Could you please clarify the below setup/ implementation direction:

1. I need to deploy Modeshape to a web server (jboss 6.1 atleast), probably jboss 7 as there is an installer available. Correct? Also, any possible issues in interaction from external JEE application deployed on jboss EAP 4.0.x?
2. Need to add binary store location for storing files in filesystem (Dont want to complicate by adding a DB). Any difference between Standard and Composite binary stores?
3. Inifispan cache is used only for properties/ metadata and the Binary store location is used to persist files. Correct?
4. Is infinispan cache persistent after restart or should these properties and metadata be saved elsewhere?
5. To access the Modeshape repository from my JEE web application, I need to use the webdav api. I won't be able to use RestAPI as I need to upload/ download PDF files. Is this correct? Also, appreciate if you throw more insights on the webdav api/ any possible setup steps
6. I need to replicate the content to the backup Modeshape server setup nightly. Are there any utilities available for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Sorry I'm not expert in JBoss but ModeShape is pure Jboss product and documentation is comprehensive on this. I think that is well defined with JBoss EAP 7. You could use WebDav or Rest to communicate between ModeShape and your application on JBoss 4.x to avoid integration in Jboss EAP 4.x.

2 - Standard Binary Storage allow store on a file in file system whereas composite store is able to aggregate several binary stores of the type: file, infinispan, database or custom. I Think you only need standard binary store (org.modeshape.jcr.value.binary.FileSystemBinaryStore).

3 - Yes it's correct. Metadatas and binaries are separated in different stores. Modeshape use infinispan to store metadatas in memory (and you could persist them with cacheStore) but binaries are in another store (FileSystem for example).

4 - Infinispan cache is persisted through cacheStore (FileSystem or JDBC or NoSQL or Clouds) within each transaction on ModeShape. If a file or folder is created in ModeShape, Infinispan store this information through cacheStore immediately.

5 - to upload or download files, it's possible to use WebDav or Rest. Rest also provide uri to upload file : [see rest api documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE/REST+Service+3.x#RESTService3.x-18.Createabinaryproperty%28viarequestcontent%29)

6 - There is no utilities to admin repository but you can use programmtic backup. And ModeShape Jira has an improvement for next release to add command line repository admin tool : [MODE-1660](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/MODE-1660)